# MATLAB: multiple object instances

Tags: oop, matlab, methods

I am new to object oriented programming, especially with MATLAB. Here is a basic question about multiple instances of objects.

I describe my problem in a simplified setting.

First I defined two classes: Node and Edge, where the Node has a property value and the Edge contains a Node:

```
classdef Node < handle
  properties
    value
  end
```

and

```
classdef Edge < handle
  properties
    node1
  end
```

Then I created one node and one edge

```
n1=Node;
e=Edge;
```

and I associate this node to the edge e

```
e.node1=n1;
```

Now comes the question, if I assign the value to n1

```
n1.value=5;
```

I can refer this value from e with the expected answer:

```
e.node1.value
ans = 5
```

But if I want to delete the node n1 referring the instance in e

```
e.node1=[]
```

then the object node1 in the object e is gone, but the Node variable n1 is still there.

What I had in mind (and wanted) is that the variable n1 and e.node1 is the same thing, but it looks like the MATLAB created two instances of the Node n1, one is n1 itself and the other one is node1 inside the object e, although I can refer the value of n1 from node1.

My question is that, if I want to delete n1 from its associated e, what would be an efficient way to do so?  Any other explanations of the background of Object Oriented MATLAB are definitely welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass the objects you wish to refer to by reference as `handle.`  This will allow the reference in the workspace to match the same object referred to by the referring class.  Here's an example:

```
classdef MyEdge < handle
  properties
    node1
  end
end


classdef MyNode < handle
  properties
    value
  end
end
n = MyNode
e = MyEdge;
n.value = 7
e.node1 = n
disp(e.node1.value)
  7
n.value = 42
disp(e.node1.value)
  42
```

Here's some other extraneous info, let me know if it's just totally off track.  :-)

When you create an object in Matlab, and then save a reference to that object somewhere else, it does behave like a real OO reference.  So, `n1` and `e.node1` reference the same thing.  However, when you `e.node1=[]` you remove the reference of `n1` from the `e` object.  The `n1` object still exists in the workspace, but `e` has no reference to it.  I believe it works the way you desire, just that removing the reference, does not allow for automatic garbage collection unless there is no reference to the Matlab object in the Matlab workspace.  Something like:

```
e1 = Edge
e1.node1 = Node
```

That should accomplish the garbage collection, i.e. once `e1.node1` points to `[]` the Node object is eliminated.  However if you had:

```
e1 = Edge
e2 = Edge
e1.node1 = Node
e2.node1 = e1.node1
e1.node1.value = 5
if( e1.node1.value == 5 )
  disp('It''s equal!!')
end
```

So they each store the reference to the same object.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Actually I did subclass the Node and Edge ( forgot to say that), and I totally agree with your answer. But I am still not sure about the following question: Suppose I have an array of Node: Node(1,N), and an Edge e whose node1 contains a certain element in Node(1,N), say e.node1=Node(i). Now I want to remove Node(i). Of course I can do Node(i)=[], and the length of the array is automatically updated and so on.  But if I want to do it via the edge e, how can I affect the original array Node(1,N)? I tried e.node1=[] or e.node1=Node. This won't modify the array Node itself.